# PhpStorm Testing: Cannot select PHPUnit to run test

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I am unable to run a directory/folder as a PHPUnit test from the context menu - it offers browser debugging and running as a php script only. I can set one up tests in the "Edit configurations" panel, and they work fine, but I have hundreds of test files, and cannot set each one up individually.

At one point, in a previous project, I could <kbd>Ctrl + T</kbd> and it would run the file/test I was in as a PHPUnit test, without any previous configuration for the file. I've reviewed my setup and they look identical.

"Settings -> PHPUnit" script is set to `vendor\autoload`, default config file is pointed to local `phpunit.xml`.

"Edit Configurations -> Defaults -> PHPUnit" is set to use default configuration file.

Again, I **can** run PHPUnit tests, it just seems like my PhpStorm is no longer recognising the files as suitable for PHPUnit unless I specify each one.

PhpStorm 2017.1.3
PHPUnit 5.7.20
PHP 5.6

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you try clearing caches via File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart?

Answer (score -1):

With Run this will send your script to php. With debug this will execute the phpunit tests you've configured.